# How to print regex match results in python 3?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, match

I was in IDLE, and decided to use regex to sort out a string. But when I typed in what the online tutorial told me to, all it would do was print:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000031D7E68>
```

Full program:

```
import re
reg = re.compile("[a-z]+8?")
str = "ccc8"
print(reg.match(str))
```

result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000031D7ED0>
```

Could anybody tell me how to actually print the result?

Comment: try `print(reg.match(str).group())`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to include  `.group()` after to the `match` function so that it would print the matched string  otherwise it shows only whether a match  happened or not. To print the chars which are captured by the capturing groups, you need to pass the corresponding group index to the `.group()` function.

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile("[a-z]+8?")
>>> str = "ccc8"
>>> print(reg.match(str).group())
ccc8
```

Regex with capturing group.

```
>>> reg = re.compile("([a-z]+)8?")
>>> print(reg.match(str).group(1))
ccc
```

> [re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.
>
> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.

Comment: Problem is, when there is no match I get ** "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"**

Answer (score 1):

If you need to **get the whole match value**, you should use

```
m = reg.match(r"[a-z]+8?", text)
if m:                          # Always check if a match occurred to avoid NoneType issues
  print(m.group())             # Print the match string
```

If you need to extract a part of the regex match, you need to use [*capturing groups*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in your regular expression. Enclose those patterns with a pair of unescaped parentheses.

To only print captured group results, use **[`Match.groups`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups)**:

> Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern. The default argument is used for groups that did not participate in the match; it defaults to None.

So, to get `ccc` and `8` and display only those, you may use

```
import re
reg = re.compile("([a-z]+)(8?)")
s = "ccc8"
m = reg.match(s)
if m:
  print(m.groups()) # => ('ccc', '8')
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/q4d0CT)