# Regex in python. How to simplify my example?

Tags: python, regex

I'm new at Python programming. Right now I'm struggling with simplifying my existing code. Here is the exercise: develop a pattern which will match the telephone number in format `(xxx) xxx-xx-xx` AND `xxx-xxx-xx-xx`. What I've come up with so far:

```
patt = "\(?\d{3}\)?\s?-?\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
```

It works perfectly. But the problem is obvious: if I have an optional pattern, say, `"(specific-patter-ffddff445%$#%)--ds"` before some kind of fixed pattern, I will have to put "?" symbol before EVERY symbol in the optional pattern. How can I combine all symbols and put just one "?" mark?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is this an exercise or a *real* problem? In case it's the latter - remove all non-digit characters from the string and check that you're left with a 10-digit number. That should cover all special use-cases.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand either. You can use a group to make a sub-pattern optional: `(?:xyz)?` makes the whole string `xyz` optional. But if you want to say that each character is optional independently of the others, you have to write `x?y?z?`. There's no shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

So what you have matches all kinds of incorrect formats. For example:

> 012)345-67-89
>   (012 345-67-89

What you want is an option, which regexes provide you: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Something like this would be preferable:

```
patt = '(?:\(\d{3}\) |\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
```

This will match *either* "(xxx) " or "xxx-" as a prefix to "xxx-xx-xx". And will not match either of the error strings listed above.

`?` should only be used in the event that what it operates on is truly optional.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I print the result?

Comment: @trollpidor So that's sort of a second question. Which is great, I'm all about learning. But I'd encourage you to take a moment to search if the answer has already been given before asking. In this case you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26438345/2642059

Comment: @trollpidor If this solves your problem I'd encourage you to click the check mark to the left of this answer to accept.